# How to making new table in mysql using php when we have add more field button in form

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a school management system in php. In my new lessons page I want to have an "add more field button" to allow users define more lessons. How can I achieve that?

How do I write php code to insert a new SQL line for each new field?

My code is :

```
<?php

/**
 * @author AmirMohammad
 * @copyright 2016
 */

include('../ss_engine/config.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $lessons[] = $_POST['lesson'];    
    $sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS darsha(
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `sid` INT(6) NOT NULL,
        `firstname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `lastname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `class` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        $lessons FLOAT NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
        ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";        
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'Error adding data'.$conn->error;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>تعریف دروس</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST">
<table style="border: 1px solid #454545;width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td>lesson 1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lesson 2</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lesson 3</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lesson 4</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lesson 5</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="submut" name="submit" /></td>
<td><button>add new field</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/topics

Comment: what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @kikuyu1, he wants to click a button, add a new `<tr><td>lesson n</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td></tr>` and be able to deal with it in PHP when he hits `submit`. I'd like to know that too.

Comment: @Amir, You will need to use jQuery to dynamically add the new `<tr>` but I don't know how to deal this new `<tr>` with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the javascript to dynamically add the lesson. and you i have changed php code also for dynamically adding the fields.

```
                   <?php

        include('../ss_engine/config.php');


        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $lessons[] = $_POST['lesson']; 
            $lesson_string;
            foreach($lessons as $lesson)
            {
              $lesson_string=$lesson.'FLOAT NOT NULL ,';
            }
            $sql='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS darsha(
                `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `sid` INT(6) NOT NULL,
                `firstname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `lastname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `class` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'.
                $lesson_string .'
                PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
                ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci';        
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if($result) {
                echo 'success';
            } else {
    echo 'Error adding data'.$conn->error;
}
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>تعریف دروس</title>
        </head>
        <script>
            $('#addNew').click(function() {
                var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
           $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>lesson '+rowCount + '</td><td>         <input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td></tr>');
        });
        </script>
        <body>

        <form action="" method="POST">
        <table style="border: 1px solid #454545;width: 100%;" id="myTable">
        <tr>
        <td>lesson 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>lesson 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>lesson 3</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>lesson 4</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>lesson 5</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lesson[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submut" name="submit" /></td>
        <td><button id="addNew">add new field</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Error log : Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartSchool\admin\lessons.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: lesson_string in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartSchool\admin\lessons.php on line 15
Error adding dataYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SE' at line 6

Comment: @AmirMohammadRivand it was error for . after lesson_string i have edited the response now it is running

Comment: hey , thank you , i have edited some parts of your code and solve the problem.